# IntelliJ "Closure" folding in Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I really liked IntelliJ's code folding where it would fold an anonymous inner class with one method into a Lambda lookalike.

However, this only works in Java <=7. Even if you explicitly write an anonymous inner class in Java 8, IntelliJ will never fold it that way.
Is there a way to enable this kind of folding in IntelliJ with Java 8, possibly with a plugin?

Comment: I am opposed against using Lambdas as they remove valuable information from the actual code file (which listener I'm implementing, what the method's called, etc.) for no real benefit when the IDE can fold the code for readability.

Comment: Have you tried asking on IntelliJ's forums?

Comment: It's not purely a matter of preference. There are semantic and performance differences between lambdas and anonymous classes. You should also consider that lambdas are becoming widely accepted and preferred, unless you never plan on sharing your code with others.

Comment: @shmosel I'm mostly talking about cases of Listeners and Runnables. Do Lambdas somehow skip the creation of "something like an anonymous class"? A lot of performance studies are still a big vague on everything.

Comment: It depends, but it definitely can.

Comment: I may adapt to Lamdas then. They might have removed this on purpose.